# No way to resolve conflict between "Zlib.Portable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am building my VB.Net console application and I am now getting a compilation error:

> Warning       No way to resolve conflict between "Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=431cba815f6a8b5b" and
> "Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

> Choosing "Zlib.Portable, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=431cba815f6a8b5b" arbitrarily. GoogleAuthandSync

[image]

For some reason that assembly is listed twice.

I realise that one is set to a version and for some reason the other is set to null. How do I resolve this issue?

## Update

Actually, in that list one is Zlib.Portable and the other Zlib.portable.signed.

I have tried uninstalling both packages and re-installing them and same error.

Comment: @AdrianMole Those line numbers don't relate to the errors. That is just the source file by coincidence.

Comment: Have you looked in the proj file and see if the answer jumps out at you?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I couldn't see anything there. At the moment I have taken the bold step of uninstalling both the Zlib nuget packages and recompiling the project. It has no errors and it working.

Comment: NICE! :)  I am glad it is working for you now.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Since your problem has been solved, you can post your answer here and [accepte it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). so that it will informs others that your issue is resolved, and pins the answer to the top so others reading your question read that answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the Nuget Package Manager to remove the two Zlib.Portable / Zlib.portable.sign packages from my project. It now compiles will no errors and appears to function without any problems.